# Proving $(f \circ g)_{*}= f_{*} \circ g_{*}$

Tags: general-topology, function-and-relation-composition

I have two continuous functions $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$ such that $f \circ g =id_Y$ and $g \circ f =id_X$. If I induce maps $f_{*}$ and $g_{*}$ everywhere I search tells me that it's clear that $(f \circ g)_{*}= f_{*} \circ g_{*}$.

Does anyone have a simple explicit proof why this is?
Sorry if I'm missing something completely obvious.

Comment: how are defined $f_*$ and $g_*$ ?

Comment: They are maps between the homology groups $f_{*} : H_n X \to H_n Y$ and $g_{*} : H_nY \to H_nX$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need the extra assumptions. As far as I know the induced map in homology is defined as
$$f_\ast[x]=[f(x)],$$
from which it trivially follows, by associativity of composition of maps, that
$$(f\circ g)_\ast[x]=[(f\circ g)(x)]=[(f(g(x))]=f_\ast[g(x)]=f_\ast\circ g_\ast[x].$$

See page 120 (in the pdf) of Hatcher https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes perfect sense :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)