# $(f + g)_* = f_* + g_*$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, group-homomorphism

Prove: for any maps $f,g : \Sigma X \rightarrow Y$ , then
$(f + g)_* = f_* + g_* : H_*(\Sigma X) \rightarrow H_*(Y )$. And prove the same for cohomology

I know how to prove the composition as here [Proving $(f \circ g)_{*}= f_{*} \circ g_{*}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845876/proving-f-circ-g-f-circ-g) , but here this map is from the homology of the suspension of the space not the space itself. could anyone help me in proving this, please?

**The meaning of addition of $f,g$ in this context is:**

As for adding functions:  for any space  X  and any space  Y,  $[\Sigma X, Y ]$   is a group (because the suspension is a co-$H$ space).  Therefore,  if  $f, g: \Sigma X \to Y$,  then  there is also their sum  $f + g: \Sigma X \to Y.$

Explicitly, you pinch the equator of the suspension to get a wedge of two copies of $\Sigma X$, and then apply $f$  to the top wedge summand and  $g$  to the bottom wedge summand.

Comment: What do you mean by $f+g$?

Comment: I guess it is the ordinary $+$ sign @freakish

Comment: Let me clarify: you take two functions $f,g:\sum X\to Y$. How do you add them without any addition on $Y$? Is this somehow induced from $\sum X$? But how? I assume that the resulting function is supposed to be $f+g:\sum X\to Y$. But what is $(f+g)(x)$?

Comment: I do not know @freakish let me think

Comment: I really do not know @freakish

Comment: @freakish do you mean that the definition has something wrong in the codomain? or you just trying to understand?

Comment: If you are asking a question you should do your best to make sure that you formulate a question that makes sense and that you understand your own question. If you don’t understand your own question, that should signal to you that you’re asking the wrong question. Here your question should be “What does “+” mean in this context?” The answer to this question is that it is induced by the pinch map “SX \rightarrow SX \vee SX”. For the simplest example, think of pinching a circle. This gives the addition on the fundamental group.

Comment: @ConnorMalin so you are saying that the statement of my question should be corrected?

Comment: Your question makes sense to someone who has seen algebraic topology, but an answer will not be helpful to you because you do not know what your question is about. It is like if I asked a question about the interaction between differential equations and Sobolev spaces, sure that probably makes sense to ask, but I don't know anything about either, so an answer to that won't help me.

Comment: So what should I understand thoroughly to answer that question? could you clarify for me please? @ConnorMalin .... regardless of the insulting tone I feel in your speech.

Comment: I’m sorry it comes across that way, in the future I’ll consider my words more carefully. It wasn’t intended to insult.

Comment: No problem .... I always feel like you want to help me but I am provocating you with my ignorance. @ConnorMalin .... what about the first part of my previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117785/discussion-between-hard-and-connor-malin).

Comment: From a neutral observer's position: You were criticized, but not in an insulting tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is adapted from Lemma 4.60 of Hatcher. The original argument there relies on chasing elements through diagrams. Here I present a more categorical version of the proof.

Note that I have deviated a little bit from Hatcher's notation by using both $\times$ and $\oplus$ in places where he uses $\oplus$ only, even though the direct sum and direct product of two summands/factors are the same. This is to differentiate between maps into vs. out of the direct product/sum, so that it's clear which limit/colimit diagram we are using, and makes it obvious what changes when we dualize.

---

As clarified by the discussion in the comments as well as your edit, the map $f + g$ is the composition $\Sigma X \xrightarrow{c} \Sigma X \vee \Sigma X \xrightarrow{f\vee g} Y$, where $c$ is the "pinch" map that quotients out an equatorial copy of $X$ in the suspension. Applying the homology functor to this, we get the map $(f+g)_*$. We want to prove that this map is in fact equal to $f_* + g_*$.

The key idea is to think of $f_* + g_*$ as the composition of the diagonal homomorphism $\Delta: H_\bullet(\Sigma X) \to H_\bullet(\Sigma X) \times H_\bullet(\Sigma X)$ given by $x\mapsto (x, x)$ with the direct sum $f_*\oplus g_*$. Now recall that $H_i(\Sigma X\vee \Sigma X) \cong H_i(\Sigma X) \oplus H_i(\Sigma X)$. Thus if we can show that the following diagram commutes, and the two vertical arrows cancel (i.e. $j$ is the inverse of $(i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*})$), then we will have obtained the equality between the composition of the top row, which by definition is just $(f+g)_*$, and the composition of the curved arrows at the bottom, which is $f_*+g_*$, since $$f_* + g_* = (f_*\oplus g_*)\circ\Delta = (f\vee g)_* \circ (i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}) \circ j \circ c_* = (f\vee g)_* \circ c_* = (f+g)_*\ .$$

[image: Diagram 1]

Now we tackle this proof in three steps. First we show that the triangle on the right commutes.
The isomorphism $i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}: H_\bullet(\Sigma X)\oplus H_\bullet(\Sigma X)\to H_\bullet(\Sigma X\vee \Sigma X)$ is induced by the inclusion maps $i_1, i_2: \Sigma X \hookrightarrow \Sigma X\vee \Sigma X$. Since $(f\vee g)\circ i_1 = f$ and $(f\vee g)\circ i_2 = g$, using the universal property of direct sums, we can show that the composition $(f\vee g)_*\circ (i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*})$ is the direct sum map $f_*\oplus g_*$. (See below for the relevant diagram. The horizontal arrows at the bottom are the canonical injections into the direct sum.)

[image: Diagram 2]

Next we want to construct the inverse of $i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}$. Consider the maps $q_i: \Sigma X \vee \Sigma X \to \Sigma X, i = 1, 2$ that are identity on the $i$-th component, and constant on the other component. It's clear that $q_1\circ i_1$ and $q_2\circ i_2$ are the identity maps, and $q_1\circ i_2$ and $q_2 \circ i_1$ are constant maps, hence an easy calculation shows that $q_{1*}\times q_{2*}$ is the inverse of $i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}$.

Finally to show that the left triangle commutes, note that $q_1\circ c$ and $q_2\circ c$ are both homotopic to the identity. (Think of this homotopy as sliding the equator to one of the poles.) This means that the induced maps $q_{1*}\circ c_*$ and $q_{2*} \circ c_*$ are equal to the identity, so $(q_{1*}\times q_{2*})\circ c_*$ is the diagonal map. (We can also draw a diagram for this proof. Even though it will seem a bit trivial, when we dualize it to prove the cohomology case later, it will become more useful.)

[image: Diagram 3]

This completes the proof.

---

For the cohomology version of the statement, you essentially dualize all diagrams (reverse all arrows, direct sums become direct products and vice versa), and argue that in diagram 1 the top composition, which becomes $(f+g)^*$, is equal to the bottom composition, which becomes $f^* + g^*$. The central idea is similar, which is to break up $f^* + g^*$ into the composition of $f^*\times g^*$ with the addition $(x, y)\mapsto x+y$. The former is the curved arrow on the right, now pointing from $H^\bullet(Y)$ to $H^\bullet(\Sigma X)\times H^\bullet(\Sigma(X)$, and the latter is the curved arrow on the left, from $H^\bullet(\Sigma X)\times H^\bullet(\Sigma X)$ to $H^\bullet(\Sigma X)$. Commutativity on the left and right follows from the dualization of diagrams 2 and 3, respectively.

---

As an addendum, I want to relate this proof back to the diagram chasing in Hatcher. The commutativity of the diagrams that I'm proving here can be phrased as maps having equal values on all elements. So saying that $(f\vee g)_*\circ (i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}) = f_*\oplus g_*$ is the same as saying for all $(x, y) \in H_\bullet(\Sigma X)\oplus H_\bullet(\Sigma X)$, we have $(f\vee g)_* (i_{1*}(x) + i_{2*}(y)) = f_*(x) + g_*(y)$. To prove this, you need only show it for the generators, which are of the form $(x, 0)$ and $(0, y)$. Similarly, to prove that $(q_{1*}\times q_{2*}) \circ c_* = \Delta$, you show that $(q_{1*}\times q_{2*})(c_*(x)) = (x, x)$ for all $x\in H_\bullet(\Sigma X)$. This is the route that Hatcher takes.

Comment: Are $q_1, q_2$ doing the jobs of the folding map?

Comment: @hard Are you referring to the folding map [as in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2686278/165060)? If so, then $q_1$ and $q_2$ are not really the same thing. There the folding map is defined on the wedge sum of the codomain of $f$ and $g$, but here $q_1$ and $q_2$ are defined on the wedge sum of the domain of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @hard The reason why that answer needs the folding map is because the notation $f\wedge g$ means something different there. Given $f, g: X\to Y$, what the other answer means by $f\wedge g: X\wedge X\to Y\wedge Y$ is the map that sends points in the first summand of $X\wedge X$ into the first summand of $Y\wedge Y$ according to $f$ and ditto the second summand but using $g$ instead. In other words it's given by $(x,0)\mapsto (f(x), 0)$ and $(0,x)\mapsto (0,g(x))$.

Comment: @hard What I mean here by $f\wedge g: X\wedge X \to Y$ is the map that sends points in the first summand of $X\wedge X$ into $Y$ itself by $f$, and ditto the second summand but by $g$. In other words $(x,0)\mapsto f(x)$ and $(0,x)\mapsto g(x)$. This is also the convention that Hatcher uses. My $f\wedge g$ is the same as the other answer's composed with the fold map. Note also that the fold map is just identity maps wedged with itself, according to my convention.